# Not getting the correct item tax label

Tags: expresso-store, tags, tax

Because we're still on EE 2.7.3, I'm using 2.2.0 of EXP:Store, and I'm running into a problem with itemised taxes.

We have items at 2 tax rates, 6% and 21%, separated into categories (and as luck would have it, there's only 1 6% category while there are 15+ 21% cats).

When I need to itemise each item's tax in the checkout list:

```
<td>{item_tax} ({tax_percent}%)</td>
```

Seems simple, except that while the first tag renders the correct tax, the second doesn't give the correct rate. I'm clearly missing something...

Comment: What's the value of `tax_percent`? Is it always one and not the other (6% or 21%)?

Comment: It tends to be the lower of the two values in the label (6%) in the label field, but the correct value is calculated in the actual tax_item value

Answer (score 1):

When you are using multiple tax rates, you need to use the `{adjustments}` loop to display each of them individually. The `{order_tax}` and `{item_tax}` variables will only display aggregate taxes so aren't suitable for dealing with multiple taxes.

"Adjustments" in Store are basically extra line items which are not real products (for example: discounts, shipping, and taxes). Each order can have many adjustments to the order total. See the [checkout tag adjustments documentation](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#adjustments_loop) for more information.

You can loop through the adjustments and display totals for each tax rate in the checkout or order tags like this:

```
{adjustments}
    {if adjustment:type == "tax"}
        {adjustment:name} ({adjustment:percent}%): {adjustment:amount} 
    {/if}
{/adjustments}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay - I've been traveling for a few days (vacation, really) and it seems I've not been using adjustments correctly. Or at least it seems that way after trying your tests with 3 Long Island ice teas in me. My goal is to have each line item reflecting the correct individual price, tax and shipping cost - I've got to explore it a it, but I missed this in the online manual. Thanks..

Comment: Fair enough :) The `{item_tax}` variable should be correct on a per-line item basis. There is no such per-line item tax percentage variable, only `{tax_percent}` which is global to the order. There is also no such thing as per-line item shipping costs, the shipping costs are calculated across the whole order.

Comment: On thing - how do I use this with a {items} loop, like on the checkout.html example page. Putting it inside the loop seems to give me duplicate results (2 items, 2 duplicates, 3 items, 3 duplicates, etc). I'm trying to show in-line: count - item desc - item tax - item price

Comment: The `{adjustments}` loop is per-order, not per-item, so you can't use it inside the `{items}` loop. As I mentioned, `{item_tax}` is the only variable you can use inside the `{items}` loop.